# Fourier transform of a difficult signal

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I have to calc the Fourier transform of the following signal:

$$e^{-2n}u(n)\delta (n-3)$$

I have tried the following solution:

$$\frac{1}{1-e^{-2}e^{-j2 \pi \nu }}$$

Is this correct? If not, can you give me an help? Thank you.

Comment: Difficult? Isn't it just a single pulse?

Comment: I have difficult to solve this... can you help me?

Comment: Is $u(n)$ the unit step?  Is $\delta(n-3)$ a Dirac Delta?  If so, just use the "sifting" property.

Comment: Note that $f (n) \delta (n-3) = f(3) \delta (n-3)$.

Comment: I'm out of games... can someone give me the solution? I know that $e^{-2(n-3)}u(n-3)\delta (n-3)$ but now??

Comment: Is the signal a sum over n or just a particular n?

Comment: All you need to do is to compute the discrete-time Fourier transform of a single pulse and then scale it. In other words, you can solve it in seconds by looking at a DTFT table.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo and about the exponential?

Comment: The exponential does not matter. Recall that $f (n) \delta (n-3) = f(3) \delta (n-3)$.

Comment: Is this right? $\frac{1}{1-e^{-j2 \pi \nu }} e^{-j6 \pi v}$

Comment: @BigShow That does not look right.

Comment: can you give me the solution?